# Declaring an Index as unique in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, performance, indexing, unique

If I know an index will have unique values, how will it affect performance on inserts or selects if I declare it as such.

If the optimiser knows the index is unique how will that affect the query plan?

I understand that specifying uniquenes can serve to preserve integrity, but leaving that discussion aside for the moment, what are the perfomance consequences.

Comment: Integrity in your database is almost always of paramount importance.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Long story short: if your data are intrinsically `UNIQUE`, you will benefit from creating a `UNIQIE` index on them.**

See the article in my blog for detailed explanation:

- [**Making an index `UNIQUE`**](http://explainextended.com/2009/04/23/making-an-index-unique/)

---

Now, the gory details.

As **@Mehrdad** said, `UNIQUENESS` affects the estimated row count in the plan builder.

`UNIQUE` index has maximal possible selectivity, that's why:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    table1 t2, table2 t2
WHERE   t1.id = :myid
        AND t2.unique_indexed_field = t1.value
```

almost surely will use `NESTED LOOPS`, while

```
SELECT  *
FROM    table1 t2, table2 t2
WHERE   t1.id = :myid
        AND t2.non_unique_indexed_field = t1.value
```

may benefit from a `HASH JOIN` if the optimizer thinks that `non_unique_indexed_field` is not selective.

If your index is `CLUSTERED` (i. e. the rows theirselves are contained in the index leaves) and non-`UNIQUE`, then a special hidden column called `uniquifier` is added to each index key, thus making the key larger and the index slower.

That's why `UNIQUE CLUSTERED` index is in fact a little more efficicent than a `non-UNIQUE CLUSTERED` one.

In `Oracle`, a join on `UNIQUE INDEX` is required for a such called `key preservation`, which ensures that each row from a table will be selected at most once and makes a view updatable.

This query:

```
UPDATE  (
        SELECT  *
        FROM    mytable t1, mytable t2
        WHERE   t2.reference = t1.unique_indexed_field
        )
SET     value = other_value
```

will work in `Oracle`, while this one:

```
UPDATE  (
        SELECT  *
        FROM    mytable t1, mytable t2
        WHERE   t2.reference = t1.non_unique_indexed_field
        )
SET     value = other_value
```

will fail.

This is not an issue with `SQL Server`, though.

**One more thing:** for a table like this,

```
CREATE TABLE t_indexer (id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, uval INT NOT NULL, ival INT NOT NULL)
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ux_indexer_ux ON t_indexer (uval)
CREATE INDEX ix_indexer_ux ON t_indexer (ival)
```

, this query:

```
/* Sorts on the non-unique index first */
SELECT  TOP 1 *
FROM    t_indexer
ORDER BY
        ival, uval
```

will use a `TOP N SORT`, while this one:

```
/* Sorts on the unique index first */
SELECT  TOP 1 *
FROM    t_indexer
ORDER BY
        uval, ival
```

will use just an index scan.

For the latter query, there is no point in additional sorting on `ival`, since `uval` are unique anyway, and the optimizer takes this into account.

On sample data of `200,000` rows (`id == uval == ival`), the former query runs for `15` seconds, while the latter one is instant.

Comment: Is there a significant difference between hash joins and nested loop joins? It's not clear if you're suggesting that the distinction justifies one or the other.

Comment: For the query above, HASH JOIN's are more efficient on non-selective indexes, NESTED LOOP's are more efficient on selective ones. UNIQUE index is the most selective index ever, and the optimizer will take the index uniqueness into account when estimating selectivity and choosing the join algorithm.

Comment: Are you saying then that there's not a general answer (it depends heavily on the query)? Is there no easy answer to this?: if the index *could* be unique, should I make it unique or not?

Comment: Yes, if the index could be unique, you certainly should make it unique. There is no benefit from using non-UNIQUE index on intrinsically UNIQUE data. UNIQUE helps the SQL Server to understand that the data are really unique and optimize the algorithms.

Answer (score 4):

Of course the optimizer will take uniqueness in consideration. It affects the expected row count in query plans.

Answer (score 1):

Performance is negatively affected when inserting data. It needs to check the uniqueness.

Comment: And positively affected when selecting data: the optimizer can exploit the uniqueness.

Comment: There is no performance difference between inserting a field into UNIQUE and non-UNIQUE index. The engine should parse the B-tree anyway, uniqueness just affects the decision whether to insert this value into given place in the B-tree or not.

Comment: I'm very curious about this, too. Benchmarks or credible sources would be much appreciated.

Comment: Performance is negatively affected when inserting data into a non-unique index; it has to check the uniqueness or not, and deal with adding the new row into the pre-existing slot or creating a new slot.  There isn't much difference.

Comment: Found this thread: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic651562-360-1.aspx#bm652904

"The optimizer will take into account when an index is unique and it can improve performance, but it really does depend on the query."
(...)
"It will slow down inserts slightly, but probably not enough to notice."

I think, it doesn't matter much.

Answer (score 1):

I've just tested this on my machine for a Production table containing more than 1 million rows because I figured it was a good test.  The results were interesting, here's the raw numbers:

-- No Index:

```
    Setup Time: 8888, Insert Time: 501690
```

-- Unique Constraint:

```
    Setup Time:   42, Insert Time: 488030
```

The Setup consisted of getting the Maximum of the field that I was adding the Unique Constraint to - so logically the performance was dramatically increased by adding the constraint.  This would also improve performance when searching by this foreign key.

Interestingly the Insert Time improved slightly as well (by 2.7228%), so only positive impacts [in my test case] of adding the Constraint (+ inherent index).

Testing shows only positive impacts from adding the constraint - no performance impact.

NOTE: For our test system I expect the values to almost always be unique, so I didn't test inserting non-unique values, in this data it truly is an exception - and not something we need to be performant.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will be taken into consideration by the query engine.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps more important: the uniqueness will protect the data integrity. Performance would a reason to ignore this.

Performance could be affected positively or negatively or not at all: it would depends on the query, if the index is used etc